# nginx reverse proxy and allow some file extension only

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

I setup nginx reverse proxy as below config and it's working file

But i want this nginx only allow some file extension  such as  html, png, php, svg, jpg, css, js  ..

and block other extension , i dont know how to do this after many test and follow lot of guide

Thanks

```
server {
    
     listen 443 ssl ;
     listen 8080 ;
   
    
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;
    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
   
    server_name mydomain.net;  
   
   
    
     location / {
       proxy_pass https://172.16.0.1:8080/;  # foward all request to another website
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;       
        
        }  

    
  
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple is to check the URI via regex:

```
if ($uri !~ \.(html|png|php|svg|jpg|css|js)$) {
    return 403;
}
```

To also allow the URIs without extension, use

```
if ($uri !~ /([^./]*|[^/]*\.(html|png|php|svg|jpg|css|js))$) {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro
Anyway how to allow the url that not  contain any file extension? such as hxxp://mydomain.com/abc/xyz

Comment: @AnthonyChen Updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you ver much, im very bad at regex, can you help me to modify the regex to disable case sensitive checking in file extension and also allow uri contains "robots.txt"

Comment: @AnthonyChen Try `if ($uri !~* /(robots\.txt|[^./]*|[^/]*\.(html|png|php|svg|jpg|css|js))$) { ... }`. Note the `!~*` instead of `!~`, it makes the regex matching case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank you  Ivan, the regex workings as descripbed.  You're  professional at this

Comment: @AnthonyChen StackOverflow way of thanking for the working answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.) :)